# Comments removed from swift files when make a framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have built up framework files of swift.

In general,if we built up framework with objective c files with comments,show up in header files but when i added comment in swift file and when import framework and access that class it will not show up any comment and also not editable to put comment.

For objective it have header file so we can add comment and can display comment.

How to do same for swift file?
Any one have idea?Please share.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation comments](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) (with `/** ... */` or `/// ...`) will be retained in Swift generated interface files. There are several additional features you can use like `- Returns:` and `- Parameter:`. More information is in the [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/).